# Replace pattern in all columns except in specific column

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I would like to replace "colon" from each columns except from first column as it is.

```
]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1:NA:58745598:23,0:--:.:TRA:BND00068094:NA:NA:chr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.:NA:58745598:0,4:--:.:TRA:126434_2:NA:NA:chr10_8544903-chr9_67290501
```

desired output

```
]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1NA5874559823,0--.TRABND00068094NANAchr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.NA587455980,4--.TRA126434_2NANAchr10_8544903-chr9_67290501
```

tried:

```
sed 's/(chr*.)*.[^: ]//g'
```

NOTE: don't need to define the columns as ":" are not fixed after first four columns, it can be anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're thinking in terms of "columns", you definitely want awk to parse your stuff. Ideally, you have acces to GNU awk.

Try this:

```
awk '{for(x=2;x<=NF;x++){gsub(":","",$x)}}1'
```

Test case:

```
$ echo "]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1:NA:58745598:23,0:--:.:TRA:BND00068094:NA:NA:chr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.:NA:58745598:0,4:--:.:TRA:126434_2:NA:NA:chr10_8544903-chr9_67290501" | awk '{for(x=2;x<=NF;x++){gsub(":","",$x)}}1'
]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1NA5874559823,0--.TRABND00068094NANAchr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.NA587455980,4--.TRA126434_2NANAchr10_8544903-chr9_67290501
```

Comment: But what if field one, as awk knows it, contains two colons, or zero?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Field one is not even referenced in this script, so awk just passes over it.

Comment: Thank you, its wok perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below sed command  and it worked like charm

```
command: sed "s/://2g"`
```

output

Command with input :   `echo "]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1:NA:58745598:23,0:--:.:TRA:BND00068094:NA:NA:chr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.:NA:58745598:0,4:--:.:TRA:126434_2:NA:NA:chr10_8544903-chr9_67290501"| sed "s/://2g"`

Output

```
]chr9:67290502]N SUPP_VEC=011 SVLEN=0 SVTYPE=TRA 0 0 0 0/1NA5874559823,0--.TRABND00068094NANAchr10_8544904-chr9_67290502 ./.NA587455980,4--.TRA126434_2NANAchr10_8544903-chr9_67290501
```